# Pass xml string as input to MySQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

We are using the following code sample to send data from my application to an external DB via stored procedure (SQL Server).

Here I need to support MySQL also. So based on DB selection by end user, we need to send the data to the either MySQL or SQL Server

The c# code will be running on a different machine and the DB server will be different server.

**C# Code**

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(<<MyConnectionString>>))
{
 using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(<<StoredProcedureName>>, sqlConnection))
 {
   sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("tblStudent", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = students.ToList().ToXML();
   sqlConnection.Open();
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_UpdateStudent` (@tblStudent  XML)
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO Student(StudentId,StudentName)
  SELECT    Student.value('(StudentId)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as StudentId,
    Student.value('(StudentName)[1]',  'nvarchar(100)') as StudentName
  FROM
  @tblStudent.nodes('/ArrayOfStudent/Student')AS TEMPTABLE(Student)
END
```

I searched on the web on how to pass xml string as input parameter from c# to a stored procedure. But I don't get any concrete answer.

Please advice on how to create a stored procedure with XML as input parameter and also how to pass the XML string from c# to the same.

**Note:** The above code works as expected in SQL Server. When I tried to implement the same with MySQL, I found that MySQL do not support xml as input type parameter in Stored Procedure. It looks like I need to pass the xml as normal text and parse the text in stored procedure.

Please let me know if there is more efficient way to do this.

Comment: So what happens with your current code? throws exception? doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Evk  The above code works well with SQL Server but I need to know the equivalent in MySQL. When I searched it looks like there is no xml type as input parameter in MySQL and I need to pass the xml as normal string and parse the xml in Stored procedure. I would like to know if there are any other way to implement the same in MySQL

Comment: I also didn't find built in xml support in MySql, but I did find this [article you might find useful.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3846526/Working-with-XML-Data-in-MySQL.htm)

Comment: If you want to support MySql, *don't* use the SQL Server classes, use the abstract [DbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) classes. You won't be able to get the same stored procedure to work on both databases though.

Comment: @TechJerk this might help you http://rpbouman.blogspot.in/2006/03/importing-xml-data-into-mysql-using.html

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry for my miss communication. I am not trying to use the same procedure. The c# and stored procedure will be different but I am not sure how to do it. I've the SQL Server code but now sure how to the same in MySQL

Comment: In any case, you should use the abstract classes. You can target multiple databases using the same code and a [DbProviderFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e(v=vs.110).aspx). The factory method. You could get a factory for a specific provider with [DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h508h681(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Why are you using XML at all instead of simply using two parameters for the two fields in the table? If you don't want to set the table and field names in your code, use an ORM. XML is *not* a "generic" communication type. You don't need one, because SQL can handle *any* number of parameters. It's application code that has trouble with arbitrary fields. XML as a "generic" type was used in the mid -00s but abandonded once ORMs took hold in the .NET world

Answer (score 0):

Using Load_File() imports the xml data into a local variable, while ExtractValue() then queries the XML data using XPath.  For instance, in the code below, it retrieves a count of students from the xml_content variable:

```
declare xml_content text;
 declare v_row_count int unsigned;  
 set xml_content = load_file(path);
 set v_row_count = extractValue(xml_content, concat('count(', node, ')'))
```

path: 'C:\students1.xml', node: '/student_list/student'

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I too failed to find a good answer on SO, so I was forced to do a bit of work myself!  The end result seems to work.  Adapting it for your purposes, gives you something like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE procedure `usp_InsertStudent` (ptblStudent  text)
BEGIN 

declare cnt int;
declare ptr int;
declare rowPtr varchar(100);

set cnt = (extractValue(ptblStudent, 'count(/ArrayOfStudent/Student)'));
set ptr = 0;

while ptr < cnt do
    SET ptr = ptr + 1;
    SET rowPtr = concat('/ArrayOfStudent/Student[', ptr, ']');
    INSERT INTO Student (StudentId,StudentName)
    values (extractValue(ptblStudent, concat(rowPtr, '/StudentId')),
            extractValue(ptblStudent, concat(rowPtr, '/StudentName')));

end while;  

SELECT ptr;

END;

$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

As an aside - I changed the routine name (your example was doing an insert not an update).

By way of explanation.  If you do `extractValue('/ArrayOfStudent/Student/StudentId')` you get a single result string, with all the values separated by a space.  Given that it is not so easy (in my limited experience) to split a string in MySQL, it seemed better to extract the individual values row by row (this was particularly true when there are many fields - I did first try extracting all fields at once into space separated strings and then splitting the strings into separate temporary tables each with an auto_increment id, and then joining the temporary tables on the ids, but this quickly became messy when more than three fields were required), hence the requirement to check the row count, and the use of the while loop.  This does mean that the inserts become single inserts, which is why I return `ptr` to indicate the number of rows added, rather than `row_count()` (which in this case would be 1!).

I was pleasantly pleased at the flexibility of MySQL when it came to implicit casting: I have so far tested ints, doubles and DateTimes successfully, in addition to strings - no explicit casting has to date been necessary.

On a more general level, your question also raised the issue of coding to multiple data providers.  Some years ago, a colleague of mine persuaded me to go the DbConnection route as advocated in some of the comments.  With the benefit of hindsight, this was a mistake.  The problem is, that you lose the chance to take advantage of particular features of one or other db provider as exposed through their .Net libraries.  So what I do now, is very much what you were proposing: I define my Data Access Layer by means of an interface; this interface is then implemented by one class per db provider, each using the native .Net libraries.  Thus the SQL Server implementation uses SqlConnection, the MySQL implementation MySqlConnection, the Oracle implementation OracleConnection and so on.  In this way my application does not care about the implementation details, but I am free to take advantage of features unique to one db or another.  To give a simple example: MS SQL server allows stored procedures to return multiple recordsets (with differing fields), thus allowing you to populate a complex DataSet in one call to the db;  all other dbs that I use, require one procedure per recordset, making it necessary to build the DataSet within the DAL.  To the application, there is no difference, as the Interface expects a DataSet to be returned.